# What am I doing wrong on passing data using Protocols

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to find a "cleaner-elegant" way to pass data between UIViewControllers. So, I decided to proceed using Delegates and Protocols. However, I failed on receive the data provided by my Protocol. What am I doing wrong?

***Trying to receive the protocol data and use it to populate a UITableView:***

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource, dataReceivedDelegate {

    func dataReceived(nome: String, foto: UIImage, qtd: Int) {
        nomeReceived = nome
        self.qtd = qtd
        self.itensTableView.reloadData()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var itensTableView: UITableView!
    var arrayNomes = NSMutableArray()
    var nomeReceived = ""
    var qtd:Int = 0
    var objetos = [Objeto]()

    //TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

//        let item = objetos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = itensTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! tableviewCell
        cell.nameCell.text = nomeReceived //Nil value
//        cell.imageViewCell.image = item.foto //Nil value
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return qtd
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addVc") as! adicionarNovoItemVc
        controller.delegate = self
    }
```

***Creating and setting value to the Protocol:***

```
import UIKit

protocol dataReceivedDelegate {
    func dataReceived(nome:String,foto:UIImage,qtd:Int)
}

class adicionarNovoItemVc: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldNome: UITextField!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var namePreview: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imagePreview: UIImageView!
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    var delegate:dataReceivedDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textFieldNome.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
      @IBAction func botaoAdcItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (self.namePreview!.text != nil) && (self.imagePreview!.image != nil) {

            delegate?.dataReceived(nome: self.namePreview.text!, foto: self.imagePreview.image!, qtd: 1)


            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        else {return}
}
```

Comment: Where's the code that creates and displays an instance of `adicionarNovoItemVc`? BTW - class names should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Hello @rmaddy, in the first snippet code I imported the delegate and then I filled the function. How do I should create a instance of adicionarNovoItemVc as you told me?

Comment: I always forget about your warning on setting the classes name with uppercase, sorry. I just focus on my issues and forgot the rest it was my fault.

Comment: When should a user be taken from `ViewController` to `adicionarNovoItemVc`? You have code to create an instance of `adicionarNovoItemVc` in `viewDidAppear` but that's not where it needs to be and you don't actually doing anything with the instance that you create.

Comment: The user should be taken from adicionarNovoItemVc to ViewController after pressing a button. I'm trying to implement my instance of adicionarNovoItemVc  in prepareForSegue, but also didn't work

Comment: are you trying to pass data backward, FROM `adicionarNovoItemVc ` TO `ViewController ` ??

Comment: Hello @AwaisFayyaz. Yeah, exactly!

Comment: put a break point in `dataReceived ` function in `ViewController` class. Is breakpoint firing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewController add an action to button,

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "yourStoryboarName", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addVc") as! adicionarNovoItemVc
    controller.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Once new controller is pushed on screen, you can execute 'botaoAdcItem' action and rest will get you expected result.